# django cms AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path' when trying to put manually plugin with ckeditor on blog article

Tags: python, django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I looked for it for a while without being able to find a single solution.

And I am using [nephila django-cms blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog). Thus when I edit an article content with ckeditor I can select my youtube plugin and add it.

10% of the time it works. Lol. The rest of time I have a browser error and this :

> File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py",
>    line 359, in process
>       newobj.path = self.node.get_last_child()._inc_path()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path'

And it happens when I click on the plugin. It doesn't even have time to show up.

Does someone has any clue about it ?

**EDIT**: *I change a bit the problem since I can't use any plugin that I included with CKEditor.*

**EDIT 2:** if it can help, here the detail returning by the server :

> "POST /en/admin/djangocms_blog/post/add-plugin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59276

**EDIT 3:** If anyone has any idea about a way of debugging it, I would take it. Just so you know, I wasn't coding when it happened. The project is very big and since it happens internally with CKEditor I am completely stuck.

Comment: you'll have to post your code if you want help

Comment: Yes ok, but which code since it happens with every plugin ?

Comment: the code that is causing the error. keep in mind [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And what if I don't know which code is causing it ?

No one ever experienced this with ckeditor ?

Comment: [seems to be a well known problem](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4102).

Comment: Hello, what CMS version are you using?

Comment: Hi Paulo, I am using the 3.1.3

Comment: Hello Jay, we made several fixes to the treebeard integration on 3.1.4. Please upgrade your version and run the fix-tree command. Do not run fix-tree on 3.1.3 as this could damage your data.

Comment: Currently on holidays, I will try when I am back. Thank you so much for your concern and reactivity !

Comment: @Paulo, I upgraded to django-cms 3.1.4. I did the cms fix-tree command but unfortunately the bug is still here when I try to create a new blog post and add one of the CMS_plugins from CKEDITOR..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we solved this through the github issues.
The fix was to upgrade to djangocms-text-ckeditor 2.7.1 (latest 2.7 release).